# Datasheet dynamic load and lost of parameters value from a query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a datasheet form in MS Access 2016, and I set the dynamic source via VBA code as below

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qry_GetSumEmployeesHoursByPeriodAndProject")

qdf.Parameters("projectID") = IIf(ProjectID = -1, Null, ProjectID)
qdf.Parameters("periodID") = IIf(PeriodID = -1, Null, PeriodID)

Set Me.Recorset = qdf.OpenRecordset()

qdf.Close
dbs.Close

Set qdf = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing
```

As you can see, the data is loaded via a parameterized query `qry_GetSumEmployeesHoursByPeriodAndProject` and it expects 2 parameters:

```
PARAMETERS periodID Long = NULL, projectID Long = NULL;
SELECT ...
```

Initially, when the form loads, everything is fine, but whenever I click on a column header for sorting or filtering, the form loads from the same query `qry_GetSumEmployeesHoursByPeriodAndProject`, but doesn't applies the parameters `periodID` and `projectID`, so it takes their values as `NULL`.

How can I prevent this from happening? Maybe to catch the forms' "Sort" even somehow and apply it to the query, but I was not able to find when and how that event is fired.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You probably need to add the parameters in the same order as they are defined, which you are not currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

You could place the parameters on a form instead of specifying them in the code.

Any form that happens to be open will be fine because you can make them hidden textboxes, and this way you know for sure that the parameter values will be available, not only to the query, but to any other part of the database as well.

You would refer to a the "parameter control" from elsewhere with:

```
Forms!YourFormName.YourTextboxName
```

---

### More info:

- Office.com : [Use parameters in queries, forms, and reports](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/use-parameters-in-queries-forms-and-reports-8209eb5c-1589-42e2-9b20-4181f4c7a356#__formparameters)

Comment: The actual value of the parameters is from the Form controls, for example, the PeriodID is a combo box, that has periods listed (like 1/2018, 2/2018 ... ). Same is with ProjectID. But when I click on column sort, the form "On Load" event is not fired. I found that "On Apply Filter" event is triggered when I try to sort or filter, but I can not get any value as which columns is sorted or sort order.

Comment: I did one other thing that actually "solved" the issue, but I don't like this solution at all, and I need to continue trying to fix it as it should be. What I did is, I rewrote the query in a VBA code, in a module, replacing the parameters with "string replace" in the code too. Then, on form load, I am assigning this query string as a Record Source to the form. Given that the forms' Record Source is a defined string query with no parameters, the resultset remains the same and working correctly is expected. However, again, I don't like this solution since the query is hardcoded in the code.

Comment: In cases like this, it's better to run SQL from VBA --**if you know how** (rather than having a separate query). Access's functionality of being able to design a query in the graphical query designer, save it, and then open it with a separate macro or button, is included for people that *don't know how* to run a query programmatically (like you did as a fix).  ***Hard Coding** is [by defiinition](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding), the practice of embedding an input or configuration data. A SQL query is "code", not "data". :-)  You used a roundabout way but you're darn close!

Comment: ...and unfortunately, without seeing more of your project, it's hard for me to visualize what exactly the issue is, but I've also always believed the *"THE RIGHT WAY"* is *"WHATEVER WAY WORKS without causing you to take extra steps"*.  Many would disagree with me, but I'm also a big believer in, *"If it ain't broke, don't fix it!"*  :-)